# Counting both passing and failing predicate in java 8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Suppose you have a stream of integers that represents students score.
[10,50,100,95,80,70,65,9010,100] and pass-mark is greater than or equal to 50. How do you get the number of students 'm' that failed for next 'n' students that pass. Need to start from current position examining only n+m students.

In the example, for starting position=0 and n=3[50,100,95], m=1[10].
Given a stream and number 'n', need to find out 'm'.

Comment: There is no “start from current position” in the stream API. You define one terminal operation for the entire stream; it doesn’t have to process all items, but the stream is consumed afterwards in every case.

Answer (score 3):

To count passing and failing predicates, you would use

```
.collect(
    Collectors.partitioningBy(
        n -> n > 50,
        Collectors.counting()
    )
);
```

As for skipping elements based on a predicate, streams don't support that.  You can shoehorn something ugly and make it work, but you should probably just use a regular loop.